# Is it possible to enable port in JSVC for remote debugging?

Tags: java, remote-debugging, jsvc

I am running a jsvc application which is working absolutely fine but now I need to enable one port on my application so that I can do remote debugging. I am performing above task using java.

Is there any way to achieve above task ?
I have checked all JSVC option http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html but didn't find anything.

Here is the code of adding jsvc parameter :

> private List getJSVCArgs(){
>           List jsvcArgs = new ArrayList();
>           jsvcArgs.add(jsvcDir+"/jsvc");
>           jsvcArgs.add("-pidfile");
>           jsvcArgs.add("pidfile.pid");
>           jsvcArgs.add("-outfile");
>           jsvcArgs.add("outfile.txt");
>           jsvcArgs.add("-errfile");
>           jsvcArgs.add("errfile.txt");
>           jsvcArgs.add("-wait");
>           jsvcArgs.add(String.valueOf(jvmProperties.get("-wait")));
>           jsvcArgs.add("-user");
>           jsvcArgs.add(System.getProperty("user.name"));
>           jsvcArgs.add("-home");
>           jsvcArgs.add(System.getProperty("java.home"));
>           return jsvcArgs;
>       }

Now I need to pass this "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n" to JSVC. Anyone has any idea how to achieve it ?

Comment: I got the answers of my question, Just pass as it is as in :
jsvcArgs.add(-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n);

Comment: You can make that your answer and accept it too.

Answer (score 1):

As Waheed discover himself, you can add add the needed parameters to jsvc like this:

```
jsvcArgs.add("-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8001‌​,server=y,suspend=n")‌​;
```